# Gammainc difference in Python and Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I am transfering code between Matlab and Python. However when I use `scipy.special.gammainc` I get different values than when I use `gammainc` in Matlab.

My Python code is:

```
from scipy.special import gammainc                                        
gammainc([1, 2, 3, 4], 5)                                                
array([0.99326205, 0.95957232, 0.87534798, 0.73497408])
```

However in Matlab I have:

```
gammainc([1,2,3,4],5,'lower')                                      
[0.00365984682734371, 0.0526530173437111, 0.184736755476228, 0.371163064820127]
```

I am trying to change my Python version to give me the same version as the Matlab code. I have tried instead:

```
from scipy.special import gammaincc                                   
gammaincc([1, 2, 3, 4], 5)                                               
array([0.00673795, 0.04042768, 0.12465202, 0.26502592])
```

This is closer but it is still not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

- Matlab's [`gammainc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gammainc.html) function expects the input arguments in reverse order compared to the usual [mathematical notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function). So it expects the integral limit first, then the exponent.
- Scipy's [`gammaincc`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammaincc.html) is the upper incomplete Gamma function, not the lower. For the lower version you need to use [`gammainc`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammainc.html).

So, to reproduce Matlab's result in Python with Scipy, use

```
from scipy.special import gammainc
print(gammainc(5, [1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

This [gives](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehODmzoFKvuCA1OTMxRyEztyC/qEQhPTE3NzEzL5mroCgzr0QDxtUw1VGINtRRMNJRMNZRMInV1Pz/HwA)

```
[0.00365985 0.05265302 0.18473676 0.37116306]
```